# Can not read property get of undefined Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

We are trying to build a settings form in ionic 3 but it throws different errors regularly. As the main issue, it shows Can not read property get of undefined. We are using Ionic 3 and here is the code for that page:

```
  import {  FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, ValidatorFn, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController,
        private tokenProvider: TokenProvider,
        private usersProvider: UsersProvider
      ) {
        this.tabElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

      }
           ionViewDidLoad() {
                 this.user = this.tokenProvider.GetPayload();
            this.buildSettingsForm();
            if (this.user) {
              this.GetUser(this.user);
            }

            this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => {
              this.GetUser(this.user);
            });
            this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => {
              this.GetUser(this.user);
            });

          }


              GetUser(id) {
                this.usersProvider.GetUserById(id).subscribe(data => {
                  this.user = data.result;

                });
              }
              onSubmit() {
                this.SettingsForm.reset();
              }
              ionViewWillEnter() {
                (this.tabElement as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
              }
              ionViewWillLeave() {
                (this.tabElement as HTMLElement).style.display = 'flex';
              }
            ...
              private populateForm() {
                const unusedFields = [
                  '_id',
                  '__v',
                  'username',
                  'email',
                ];

                const userInfo = Object.assign({}, this.user);
                unusedFields.forEach((field) => delete userInfo[field]);
                this.SettingsForm.setValue(userInfo);
              }

              private buildSettingsForm() {
                this.SettingsForm = this.fb.group({
                  city: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
                  country: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
                  firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
                  lastName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
                });
                this.SettingsForm.setValidators(this.minimumAge(18));
              }

              UpdateUser() {
                this.usersProvider.EditUser(this.SettingsForm.value).subscribe(
                  data => {
                  },
                  err => console.log(err)
                );
            }

            }
```

**Also here is the HTML.**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="SettingsForm" (ngSubmit)="UpdateUser()">
    <ion-list style="margin-top: 15% !important" class="scroll">
      <ion-item>
          <ion-input class="input-field" formControlName="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
   <div *ngIf="!SettingsForm.get('firstName').valid && SettingsForm.get('firstName').touched"
    class="help-block">Please choose the gender</div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input class="input-field" formControlName="lastName" name="last name" type="text" placeholder="Last name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
   <div *ngIf="!SettingsForm.get('lastName').valid && SettingsForm.get('lastName').touched"
    class="help-block">Please choose the gender</div>
        <ion-item>
...
...
  <button ion-button block class="login-button">Sign Up</button>                
    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

It shows error inside the console on each input fields line. Can the issue be inside TS? Because when I test with simple another form it works but with this TS doesn't. What can cause such issues? What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Can you also share full code of you ts including constructor?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I've just included it.

Answer (score 0):

The form you are using in the template will be undefined at startup. Use the Elvis operator to avoid null exception in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="!SettingsForm?.get('firstName')?.valid && SettingsForm?.get('firstName')?.touched"
```

Comment: @NewTechLover be sure you get all the occurances of `.get(...)`. Your error points to their parent object being null. Otherwise please post the complete error message. Definitely not a Typescript issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to me a bit unconventional in the way you initialize and work with forms. At least I used to see something closer to what is in angular.io guidance or in this tutorial by Josh: https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/

Now to your issue - the error says "get of undefined" basically that means your SettingsForm in *ngIf expression sometimes is...undefined.

Instead of get method try using this:

```
*ngIf="!SettingsForm.controls.lastName.valid && SettingsForm.controls.lastName.touched"
```

Now to avoid it to be undefined at startup - move your formBuilder init into constructor function as opposed to lifecycle hook you are using now.

Comment: I made all the changes as you said. It throws cannot read property controls of undefined

Comment: Can you share full ts file please after you added changes